# jquery an iframe to display only a "div'd" section of HTML

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to load an external page inside an iframe but only trying to display what's inside of a DIV tag.  I heard there was a way to do this with jquery and I believe I have found the correct code but I cannot get it to work correctly.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery and Frames</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($) {
var data = $('<div />').load('div.html #test');
var doc = $('#frame1')[0].contentWindow.document;
var body = $('body',doc);
$(body).html(data);
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="frame1"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my target page I'm trying to display just what's inside the div tag from.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>blah</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
    Working
    </div>
    Not Working
</body>
</html>
```

However when I load the main page it will display nothing at all in the iframe

**EDIT this has been updated with Sorin's reply

Is their a possibility since I have access to the target site that using div tags and CSS that I can accomplish the same thing with hiding tags using CSS?

Comment: the iframe won't load the page at all that the jquery points it to.  I think my jquery is wrong.

Comment: Is the page you're trying to load on the same domain?

Comment: For the final product no, it will be on a separate domain.  However I have access to the target site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
jQuery( function($) {
  var data = $('<div />').load('test1.html #testdiv');
  var doc = $('#frame1')[0].contentWindow.document;
  var body = $('body',doc);
  $(body).html(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, however still no dice.  
This is what I have now
`<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery and Frames</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery( function($) {
    $('#frame1').load('div.html #test');
   });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="frame1"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>`


And my target page




`<html>
    <head>
        <title>blah</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="test">
  Working
  </div>
  Not Working
    </body>
</html>`

Oh dear god the ugly formatting of this posting box

Comment: Why do you want to use jquery to load content in an `iframe`? You can use a `div` element instead and should work.

Comment: If you're talking about div align with an iframe I'm not sure I want to go that route, the point with using the above jquery was to strip out all the html outside of the div tags for a cleaner iframe.

Comment: I was suggesting to use this markup:`<body>
    <div id="frame1"></div>
</body>`

Comment: Well like I said earlier, my main point in not just pointing an iframe to a div tag like that is I also want to strip away all html outside of the div tags, which is what the above jquery does correct? If not then I guess I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: I have changed the answer. This will add the extra `div` inside the iframe but i think it will not be a problem.

Comment: Ok thanks!  I've updated my question with your updated answer, still no dice but I might be doing it wrong.  *facepalm*